# What to use, external calls or COM or smth else?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com

I have a large amount of C/C++ legacy code. And I want to call it from my C# managed code. There are types and functions in C++. What the best approach here?

I found out that COM is the most versatile and appropriate way to do so. But I didn't find any examples with classes. Does it support using C++'s types as .NET classes?

Comment: Bolting a COM interface on top of legacy code that was never designed to be usable from a COM client tends to be troublesome.  Pinvoke is not suitable for C++ code.  Consider writing C++/CLI wrappers, its learning curve is a lot less steep than COM and it provides plenty of versatility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the types involved can marshal easily I would say use the `[DllImport]` attribute and decorate with `marshaling` attributes as necessary.

Start reading at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/index